# Have uploaded images in questions and answers shown through HTTPS like in chat

Tags: feature-request, images, ssl, imgur, uploader

I have recently noticed (mostly because I have turned on Strict HTTPS in my browser so that it does not allow mixed content on HTTPS pages) that when one uploads an image to a question or answer using the standard in-built functionality which uploads it to imgur and puts it in this format:

```
[![enter image description here][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVpb.png
```

It makes it display it to you using HTTP rather than using HTTPS which is available. Now however in chat the same in-built upload functionality uploads it to imgur and then shows it to you through HTTPS as the same image would be uploaded and then displayed as:

```
https://i.stack.imgur.com/YqVpb.png
```

So I think that for security and consistency reasons they should both show the images through HTTPS so that when one uploads an image to a question or answer it displays it through an HTTPS connection as it does for uploaded images in chat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They should really be protocol dependent.

Instead of `http://` or `https://`, use `//`. This way, images will load based on the client setting: If the client loaded the page through `http://`, it will use `http`, and likewise for `https`.

Remember though, that Stack Exchange doesn't support `https` really, and if you really want to do that in your posts, then do it.

The issue is that not everything on the internet supports `https`. While Imgur might, other URLs may not, which could just complicate things.

Comment: Oh right, yes that does sound better. Sorry, I didn't know that you could just have `//`.

Comment: I don't see why it would complicate things if we changed it for imgur as we have done on chat, but obviously just leave all the other URLs alone that are not anything to do with SE. And you can't say that you won't do it for the main SE sites just because you can't do it for other URLs, because you've already done it in chat for imgur, and not for all the other URLs.

Comment: @ParanoidPanda Ah, I agree with that. I had the original impression that you wanted to do this for all URLs. :)